# Interval in AC spectrum of self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, spectral-theory

This may be an obvious and silly question, but I'll ask anyway. I was wondering whether  a spectrum of a self-adjoint operator with non-trivial AC part can be totally disconnected.

I know that the spectrum having measure $0$ implies no AC part. But does the spectrum being totally disconnected imply only possibly singular continuous component? From a somewhat short search, I could not find such examples. I assume however that this question either has famous counterexamples or a relatively simple proof of the statement.

Comment: Consider $L^2(0,1)$ and the multiplication operator by $x$ times the indicator function of the Cantor like set of the positive Lebesgue measure. Perhaps it provides an example you are looking for ? [see](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith–Volterra–Cantor_set)

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you for your answer. Is the argument that for any $x\in H_{ac}^{\perp}$ the associated spectral measure is supported on a set of Lebesgue measure zero? So the only way the spectrum will have positive measure if its AC part is not trivial?